# Make a hidden input in razor model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tdstyle">
        <i class="fa fa-phone iconPos" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>@Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.First(x => x.ContactDataType.Name == "BillingPhone").Detail</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.First(y => y.ContactDataType.Name == "BillingPhone").Detail)
    </td>
</tr>
```

The generated input-field from above code Is this:

```
<input id="Detail" name="Detail" type="hidden" value="0730730037" />
```

This Is incorrect because It Is not binded to the Model. How can I generate a correct hidden input of this so the binding works?

Comment: what is value in span

Comment: Set the value of the property you want to bind to in the controller, not the view (your generating `name="Detail"` because that't the name of the property your accessing in the `HiddenFor()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I want to do this in the view. Is this possible?

Comment: Why? (it belongs in the controller not the view) _Is it possible?_ - only with some awful hacks. What is the name of the property your wanting to bind to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Detail. But I can only access the Detail-property with the First-method as you can see.

Comment: The binding isn't clever enough to understand the linq statement. **All** logic should be in the controller

Comment: Make me ill, but `@{ var detail = Model.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson ......Name == "BillingPhone").Detail; }` and `@Html.Hidden(" LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Detail", detail)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ok, but If I do the binding In the controller, what should the parameters be that the controller should accept? controllername(string Detail, string value1, string value2 ...)? I think that Is awful, thats why I just use controllername(LicenseHolderDetailViewModel model)

Comment: You just bind to your model (as your currently doing) - But you have referred to it as LicenseHolderDetail**ViewModel** but everything in your previous comments suggests that is not a view model at all. A view model does not contain data models, And a view model should be a flat structure (within reason). And a view model contains only values that you need in a view. And your ceratinly never use linq queries in a view if you use a view model. Recommend you read [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: My view model contains DTO-models.

Comment: It should not contain data models!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this logic should be in controller as Stephen Muecke suggested, but if that is not possible you may try using a for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails.Length; i++){
     if (x.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails[i].ContactDataType.Name == "BillingPhone") {
       @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.LicenseHolder.LegalPerson.ContactDetails[i].Detail)
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I canä't use length because ContactDetails Is a IENumerble

Comment: what exactly is the data type of ContactDetails? is it IEnumerable<ContactDetail>?